# Where to find UA token in Ubuntu Advantage?

Tags: ubuntu-advantage, esm

I bought UA for one of my units (ran out of free tokens) and I now have that machine inside Landscape. However, if I run *apt upgrade* it tells me another 138 additional updates are available with UA Infrastructure ESM.

I've seen a lot of posts mention that you can find these tokens in Landscape but for the life of me, I can't find it!

I've also tried installing updates through Landscape but that fails when I try to approve (request is in a state that cannot be approved)

Does anyone know where to find the token so I can update manually?

Comment: your token subscription will just appear when you've registered. it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

1. Review UA status with `sudo ua status` command
2. Use your UA credentials to login at https://ubuntu.com/advantage and get the token at "Get your token" block
3. Apply the token with `sudo ua attach [TOKEN]` command
4. Review UA status with `sudo ua status` command again to see the changes

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, if I go to that page I can only claim a free token (which I already did and used) or buy a subscription (which I also already did).

I don't see any place where I can get a token, not even in Landscape..